# doesn't move to the next state in FSM, Aiogram

Tags: python, fsm, aiogram

why it doesn't move to the last state(LowPrice.result_without_photo)? for example, if I use print in each handlers, it print it except the last one.

Of course I can not to move to the last state and write this func in the current state, but this code simplified, just fo example, it has more lines, that is why I want to use a separate state, just to make code more readable

my handlers:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command("lowprice"))
async def choose_city(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Write city')
    await LowPrice.city.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=LowPrice.city)
async def hotels_quantity(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(city=answer)
    await message.answer('How many hotels do I need to show you?')
    await LowPrice.quantity_hotels.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=LowPrice.quantity_hotels)
async def if_need_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(quantity_hotels=answer)
    await message.answer('Do I need to show you hotel photos?')
    await LowPrice.photo.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=LowPrice.photo)
async def get_answer_about_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    await state.update_data(if_photo_need=answer)
    if answer == 'Yes':
        await message.answer('How many photos to show?')
        await LowPrice.quantity_photo.set()
    elif answer == 'No':
        await message.answer('Fine, I am starting to find hotels')
        await LowPrice.result_without_photo.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=LowPrice.result_without_photo)
async def result_without_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    city_id = get_id_city(data)
    await message.answer(f'city ID{city_id}')
```

my states:

```
class LowPrice(StatesGroup):
    start = State()
    city = State()
    date = State()
    quantity_hotels = State()
    photo = State()
    result_without_photo = State()
    quantity_photo = State()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because user need to write something for help you to handle message in `result_without_photo` function.

Are you sure that you really want it?
Seems you just need to execute content of `result_without_photo` after `No` answer instead of awaiting another one communication from user.